# Can the contents of a .csv be used as a vector for axis labelling in R?

Tags: r, vector, label, axis

Say I'm trying label an x-axis in the following way:

```
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"))
```

except that I want to use the values I stored to a variable "labels" from

```
labels <- read.csv("labelFile.csv", header=T)
```

When I enter "labels" after assigning it, R succesfully returns the contents with enumeration:

```
    labels
      AA
1     AB
2    AHA
3   APir
4      B
5     Ca
6  CA1or
7  CA1py
8  CA1ra
9  CA2py
10 CA3py
11   CA4
12    CE
13  cOF2
14  cOF3
15  cOF5
16  cOF6
17  DGgr
18  DGpf
19  DGsg
20 dlPF2
21 dlPF3
22 dlPF4
23 dlPF5
24 dlPF6
25   GPe
26   GPi
27    ic
28  IsCj
29     L
30    Me
31  mOF2
32  mOF3
33  mOF4
34  mOF5
35  mOF6
36   NAC
37    PL
38    Pu
39  rCG2
40  rCG3
41  rCG5
42  rCG6
43  rPAC
44     S
45    Tu
46  V1-1
47  V1-2
48  V1-3
49 V1-4A
50 V1-4B
51 V14Ca
52 V14Cb
53  V1-5
54  V1-6
55  V1wm
56 V2_L5
57  V2-2
58  V2-3
59  V2-4
60  V2-6
```

When I try this code, the following happens:

```
    axis(1, at=3*0:59, lab=c(labels))
Error in axis(1, at = 3 * 0:59, lab = c(labels)) : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 60 != 1
```

So, what I'm trying to do is get the contents of the "labels.csv" file to be listed on the x-axis at tick marks 1,4,7,10...59 (up by multiples of three each time). Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: I'm guessing that `AA` is supposed to be the first label rather than the name of the column. If so, use `header=FALSE` and the column will be given a generic name.

Answer (score 1):

I think labels is a `data.frame`, so if you write `c(labels)` you get a list with one `data.frame` in it. That explains the length error. Try this:

```
axis(1, at=3*0:59, lab=as.vector(labels$AA))
```

Comment: Thanks! That gets the job done pretty well, except that now it's displaying both the numbers and the values from the dataframe... any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe adding as.vector will fix this! Let me know if it didn't solve your problem!